# Is there any reason to buy keys on the community market?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

You can buy keys on (appearently) unlimited stock from the system itself (And its afaik the only way to obtain them, so also not like you could get 1 droped and then sell it underpriced because you have no need).

But I see soooo often people placing keys on the communitymarket, some times even the cheapest offer starting by + 0.50€ more then the price I had to pay them directly to obtain from system.

Is there any reason that 1 should buy them from communitymarket for higher price?

Or are this just offers hoping for some one stupid who doesn't know?

Comment: pretty much, No.  I never buy keys from the community market and i suppose people only sell them there for richer nicer people to buy b/c they feel like giving to the community a little.

Comment: My best guess is that prices vary depending on the country you live in. I.e. the keys cost £1.70 over in the UK but may cost $2.00 in the US. In this scenario the americans get the better deal. I dont know how it all works out all around the world but in countries where theyre cheaper - like the USA, they can sell them on the market for just above their home prices and people in say, idk, japan where it might cost $3 worth of yen to buy one key can get it cheaper. it would be mutually beneficial.

Comment: @AlexSpencer: You know comments aren't for answers? As this would be the acepted answer, since meanwhile I figgered out thats the way. especially the deal ebtween € and $ is significant. as it costs 2.2$ and also 2.2 € but the exchange rates are far off 1:1 .

Comment: @Zaibis yeah sorry, as I said I wasn't sure it was really relevant but sure okay. I can plonk it into answers if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that prices vary depending on the country you live in. I.e. the keys cost £1.70 over in the UK but may cost $2.00 in the US. In this scenario the americans get the better deal. I dont know how it all works out all around the world but in countries where theyre cheaper - like the USA, they can sell them on the market for just above their home prices and people in say, idk, japan where it might cost $3 worth of yen to buy one key can get it cheaper. it would be mutually beneficial

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the only reason:

You can only buy them in-game if you own the game. Not everyone does, but keys are still used as a universal currency throughout steam.

Comment: Sounds like a valid option. But again I still don't understand the reasons for this. I would assume there are other games with that kind of universal currency. And I can't really imagine there are that much people at all who don't have one of their friends owning one of those games with that kinds of currency items where that friend could buy 1 for me via my what ever payment information. And even if ti is that. After additional calculations I noticed the seller actually get after steam fees a little bit less then 2,20€ so its even a loose loose situation for both sides. What am I missing?!

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above said, some people dont have the game but still want to make some money, so they can buy them on the market, which results in paying a bit more then you pay ingame.

You can also use these keys from the market, and use it as a payment method, if both of the traders agree to the market price, the prices from the skins could be scaled. (Would be useful for trading with non game owners)

But another reason which i used often is the function to set a wish price, the system then automaticaly buys the keys for you on the wished price you set earlier.

But if you want to do a case opening then i recomend you buying them ingame.

Comment: I had to downvote you, since this is absolutly not what I'm asking/facing and even your posted link contradicts your claim. just clicking your link shows the following hints which proove you're wrong in any view:

Comment: Let me edit, just misunderstood the last sentence

Comment: first looking on the graph with avverage prices. The only time within the last month was the 3rd of april at 9pm, there the communitymarket price was equal to the system price. Then jsut while clicking I was able to read: "Carlo hat diesen Gegenstand für 2,50€ von Staz gekauft" and "Jesus hat diesen Gegenstand für 2,49€ von Ac!D gekauft" thats german for person 1 bought from person 2. In addition, the graph tells me that 224 items of that kind were sold on an average price of 2.48€ within the last hour. while they are sold by the game for 2,20€ Since people list and buy for that, so no err

Comment: Why should Valve buy virtual goods from you which they "produce"?

Comment: When did i say Valve buys keys from you?

Comment: " the function to set a wish price, the system then automaticaly buys the keys on the wished price you set earlier." By saying system I was refering to the game where you buy the keys on unlimited stock, assuming you shared my terminology, you say valve is buying your keys to a price you'd wish em to pay.

Comment: It buys the keys/ skins for you when the offers reach that price.

Comment: Ah ok, by "system" you refered to the market itself. but then its still missing my point, since I'm asking why people are even offering that prices.

Comment: Thats because either they want to make money or they dont need them and still dont want to make loss (fees). If you offer the key for 2.20 Euro the buyer pays ca 2.53 Euro. Then it trys to match the offer with the purchase orders on the market. A lot of the poeple buying on the market dont own the game.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Well... This is at least enough to rmeove my downvote. But still nothing I would feel I should upvote.